# Traceability information missing for Extended Classes (UML)

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, metaclass

Hope you can provide some help. I am using Enterprise Architect to do some UML modelling.

I have used the Extension relationship within the Metamodel Toolbox to extend Class 1 from metaclass Class (UML extension) so that Class 1 is a subtype of the Metaclass Class.

However, in the traceability window, when I select Class 1, I am unable to see the link/association to the metaclass from where it was extended from (which I expect to see).

I have looked into the example provided by EA and the example uses an association relationship with a stereotype of extends. With that provided example, I am able to view the traceability information and am able to see that Class 1 is  Associated to Class.

For UML, is there a difference between using association relationship with extends stereotype (as in the EA UML stereotype example) vs. using the Extension relationship within the Metamodel Toolbox?

Many thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure here, but IIRC in the former EA editions (< 9.3 or so) they actually used the `<<extends>>` stereotyped dependency. And if so it's most likely that it's still supported (without any deprecation warning).

Comment: Just verified it: they used an `<<extends>> Association` (not Dependency) up to V9.3. And - this connector still delivers the same results as an `Extension`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The Extend relation doesn't show up in the traceability view (just tested on version 15.0.1502)

You may consider that a bug and [report](https://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html) it as such to Sparx Systems.

Using an association with stereotype «extends» is not the same thing. The extension relation is defined in the UML standard, whereas the stereotype «extends» is not defined at all. («extends» in the context of use cases is a keyword, not a stereotype and it definitely has a completely different meaning)

Comment: Thank you @Geert Bellekens for confirming my suspicions, I have now reported this issue as a bug to Sparx Systems.

Answer (score 0):

In UML, the ≪extend≫ stereotype is only defined in the context of use cases. There is no definition of such a stereotype when used for an association between two classes.

So, for extending metaclasses, the formally defined extension associations are preferred.